# jQuery : select specific DOM with specific HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a menu

## HTML

```
<li class="{{{ strpos(Request::url(), 'analytics')!==FALSE ? 'active' : ''}}}">
    <a href="/analytics">
        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart analytics"></i>
        Analytics
        <span class="badge badge-success pull-right">1</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

[image]

I've tried

```
$('i.analytics  span').text(response.count.ue_profiles.total);
```

I've also tried

```
$('i.analytics > span').text(response.count.ue_profiles.total);
```

I've also tried

```
$('.analytics > span').text(response.count.ue_profiles.total);
```

They don't seem to take effect.
I thought jQuery uses the same selection as CSS.

If I want to, I can use a `find('span')` which I know for sure, it will work, but I am curious to right to do it via selector itself.

How do I overwrite that?

Comment: there a typo in your selector: `analytic` should be `analytics`

Comment: @SidneyGijzen good spot, agree. Maybe a delete question Kyo?

Comment: update  my post. changing it still not working. It's more than a typo. guys.

Comment: @Bibberty I don't mind delete it, if it was the fix.

Comment: do you run your jquery script after document.ready?

Comment: Try this `$('i.analytics ~ span').text("Test 2");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want the `sibling` operator, `span` is not a child of `i.analitycs`. `i.analytics ~ span`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator

Comment: Why can't I use this `>` ??

Comment: It works, but please answer the question I asked above.

Comment: ">" is the "child" operator, you would need the `span` to be nested INSIDE the `i.analytics` element for that to work. In your case, span is not a child of the i tag, it's a sibling of it. That's why it doesn't work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator

Comment: Thank-you for your follow up with explaination.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax would be `i.analytics ~ span` to get the sibling. What you are trying to do with the selectors you suggested is find a child node.

Here's a working solution:

```js
$('.analytics ~ span').text(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a href="/analytics">
    <i class="fa fa-bar-chart analytics"></i> Analytics
    <span class="badge badge-success pull-right">1</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The right selector in your case is sibling selector. or you can use child selector by adding a class to the `a`

```js
let total = 10;
$(document).ready(() => {
  /**
  * span is a child of a
  * $('.parent-link > span').text(total);
  **/
  
  // OR: span is a sibling to i
  $('i.analytics ~ span').text(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="{{{ strpos(Request::url(), 'analytics')!==FALSE ? 'active' : ''}}}">
    <a href="/analytics" class="parent-link">
        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart analytics"></i>
        Analytics
        <span class="badge badge-success pull-right">1</span>
    </a>
</li>
```